# How do I get charts.add command to deliver an empty chart?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

The command `charts.add` in VBA adds a new chart object to the workbook. I think hitting `F11` in Excel does exactly the same.

The problem is, that this command uses the data around the at that point selected worksheet and cell to populate the chart. If there is no data or no usable data, it returns an empty chart.

My question is: **"How can I force the command to deliver an empty chart?"**. I intend to populate the chart with VBA code thereafter.

A simple answer to the question is to create a new empty worksheet and select cell A1 on that worksheet and then create a new chart, but that is a rather ugly solution. Any help on elegant solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add additional line which will immediately remove data right after the chart appears:

```
Charts.Add 
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Clear
```

**EDIT** Alternative solution, but this will jump back to data sheet:

```
'select last cell in the sheet which is usually empty
Dim tmpSel As Range
Set tmpSel = Selection
Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).Select
'add chart
Charts.Add
'back to base sheet and select range previously selected
tmpSel.Parent.Activate
tmpSel.Select
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my opinion this is still not a very elegant solution, because it requires computational resources to first construct the graph and then delete it again. I am not sure if your solution is computationally more efficient than my ugly solution.

Comment: even it's still not 'elegant solution' this will be much more efficient compared to your idea. Alternatively, less efficient, you could try with idea I added to my answer.

Comment: BTW, if you find anything 'elegant' please share with us, I'd be glad to know it if exists.

Comment: @Guus: Computational resources?! That's a non-issue, unless you're creating thousands of charts or something. These are both good solutions. Pack them up in a Sub and you're all set. +1

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett True that. Computational issues are not-so-relevant, but I originally asked this question to find an elegant solution. A solution that requires computational effort to create something that is destroyed the next line, is not elegant. I appreciate the effort KazJaw put into answering (+1), but it is not a good answer (no accepted answer).

Comment: @Guus: It's the most elegant answer there is. You're asking for something impossible. Not accepting the answer reflects more on the question than on the answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I agree.

Comment: Elegant? In Excel? Right... You could note the selection and active cell, then select a cell that is blank and is surrounded by blanks, insert the chart, restore the selectin and active cell. Personally, creating the chart and clearing out the data hardly uses any resources, while inserting and then deleting a worksheet will cause a noticeable slowdown in the code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett But what if I am creating thousands of charts?  And what if the user who is using my code happens to have a large spreadsheet selected when they run it?

Comment: Aha!  I'm using this solution (though I wish there were something more elegant), and I just ran into a situation where more than 255 rows were selected, because I had just pasted that data into the spreadsheet (Error 1004: "The maximum number of data series per chart is 255").  I guess I have to unselect the data first :(

Comment: @JazZeus - Probably for typical charts with minimal data, computational resources are not critical.  For about 40 files, I am generating XY Scatter plots with about 100,000 rows of data.  I am only plotting 4 columns, but Excel decides to use 30+ columns with the 100,000 rows.  It was causing the OLE errors.  The ClearContents solution did not work for me.  Selecting the last cell in the sheet worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I tried using the `ActiveChart.ChartArea.Clear` property and it resulted in crashes. Then I tried `ActiveChart.ChartArea.ClearContents` after adding the chart and it gave me the desired result, which was a blank chart that I could add series to.

Answer (score 3):

I have just spent a pretty tough time with solving this. Whatever I did, the bloody excel took some data from somewhere, which was really anoying. The .ChartArea.Clear method resulted in a crash whenever I manipulated the chart afterwards (even filled with new series)

Here is my final solution from a real working project (a fragment, sorry for some user-specific variables)

```
Dim Chrt as Chart

' This is "the elegant" method
' Parameters of Add do not actually matter, we will specify all details later
Set Chrt = MySheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 100, 100).Chart

' And here we start to fill the empty (!) Chart with some useful series... :)
With Chrt

  ' Specifying chart type
  .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

  ' Positioning (Page is a range - fragment of my code)
  With .Parent
    .Top = Page(3, 1).Top
    .Left = Page(3, 1).Left
    .Width = Page.Width
    .Height = (Page.Height - (Page(4, 1).Top - Page(1, 1).Top)) ' / 2
  End With

  ' Adding a new serie
  With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "D" & Work.Cells(iFileRow, 2)
    .XValues = Range(MySheet.Cells(2, 1), MySheet.Cells(DataEnd, 1))
    .Values = Range(MySheet.Cells(2, 10), MySheet.Cells(DataEnd, 10))

    .MarkerStyle = -4142

    ' Formating the series
    With .Format.Line

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel tries to populate a brand new chart with the selected data, or with the block of data that contains the active cell.

Select a blank cell in the middle of an unused range. Without data to plot, Excel will insert a blank chart.

Answer (score 1):

i like the `ActiveChart.ChartArea.Clear` answer.

I had been doing the following, back when i did a macro in excel 2003.
It will manually delete all series in the selected chart.

```
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet

' manually delete every series that may be in a new chart
On Error GoTo 30
   yy = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
   For xx = yy To 1 Step -1
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(xx).Delete
30 Next xx
```